# Get browser events/actions/status on server using sockets in java

Tags: java, sockets, jsf

I want to get the user event(like click)/action/status(like active-idle) on server side using java sockets. I am using glassfish server, netbeans7.3.1, jdk 1.6.0_45 , JSF
Can somebody help me. Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "java sockets"? nio sockets? websockets?

Comment: simple sockets which used for client server communication in java